# CSS text fade gradient effect

Tags: css

I'm using `-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient` to create a text fade gradient effect.

Consider this: http://codepen.io/apopa116/pen/xOpjEz

By using only CSS, how can I remove the gradient mask when I reach the bottom of the div?

Comment: When you say "when I reach the bottom of the div" are you talking about scrolling? Because I don't believe CSS has any concept of where the view window is inside the document, so this probably isn't possible. (With just CSS that is, with JS it's very achievable)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add some JQuery (you would first have to add a line to import the Jquery framework) that detects when the window is scrolled all the way to the bottom of the page and the if it does, change the -webkit-mask-image property:

By adding this JS, you should be able to get what you wanted:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.box').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
           $(".box").css("-webkit-mask-image", "initial");
        }else{
           $(".box").css("-webkit-mask-image", "");
        }
    })
});
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNxYYr)

Standard JS solution equivalent (no need for JQuery import) [Credit: Andrew Bone]

```
var boxSelector = document.querySelector('.box');

boxSelector.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  if (boxSelector.scrollTop >= (boxSelector.scrollHeight - boxSelector.offsetHeight)) {
    boxSelector.classList.remove('gradient')
  } else {
    boxSelector.classList.add('gradient')
  }
})
```

Comment: Personally I would toggle a CSS class rather than having the styling in the JS, but that's mostly personal preference.

Comment: When it scrolls all the way to the bottom, the fade effect stops, but doesn't continue once you scroll up again, so my solution was a bit simplified.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to import jquery (slowing load times) just to do this? It's quite easy to do in standard JS https://jsfiddle.net/b0390hhx/

Comment: Thanks for the standard JS option. I updated my answer with your code and credited you.